# Gem not installing rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When I run `gem install rails` I get this error:

```
C:\Users\try>gem install rails
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'rails' (>= 0), here is why:
          Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - SocketError: Failed to open TCP connection to : (getaddrinfo: No such host is known. ) (https://rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)
```

I am using:

- ruby 3.0.2p107 (2021-07-07 revision 0db68f0233) [i386-mingw32]
- Windows 10 32 bits.

How can I open the TCP connection?
How do I solve the SocketError and go ahead?

Comment: I would say there is an issue with your DNS, as apparently, it cannot resolve the IP address of rubygems.org. Please, double-check your machine is able to connect to ping rubygems.org, they issue may not be installing the gem

Comment: thanks for the hint, i am still new to some terms used. how do i check the DNS, i am using windows 10 32 bits. what  are the steps for resolving the IP address of rubygems.org. and how do i check if machine is able to connect to ping rubygems.org. thanks, reference materials would help or direct answers. stack and was to meet some deadlines for a project next week.

Comment: did you run gem install bundler after install ruby? If not then do first then install rails

Comment: when i run gem install bundler this is the result: C:\Users\try>gem install bundler
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'bundler' (>= 0) in any repository. Some solutions gave this step: C:\Users\try>gem update --system
Latest version already installed. Done.

Comment: C:\Users\try>gem sources -a http://rubygems.org
https://rubygems.org is recommended for security over http://rubygems.org

Do you want to add this insecure source? [yn]  y
Error fetching http://rubygems.org:
        SocketError: Failed to open TCP connection to 3000:80 (getaddrinfo: No such host is known. ) (http://rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)

Comment: Did you solve this problem? This looks more like a network issue than anything related to Ruby itself.

Maybe you're being blocked by a firewall? Or some permission issue in Windows?

Comment: The solution was to backup my data and restore my windows 10 , after that used PowerShell as administrator and rails got installed with other gems. thanks for the ideas.